# Prove: there is no set of first order sentences such that the negation of König’s lemma is satisfied

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Prove that there does not exist a set $\Delta$ of first-order sentences
>   such that the negation of König’s lemma is satisfied.

***Negation***:
For each directed graph $T$ if $T\models\Delta$ then either $T$ is not tree or $T$ doesn't contain infinite path.

**My trial**
Let’s suppose that such $\Delta$ exists. Then, let’s extend language by two constant vertices $u,v$ and add to $\Delta$ sentences $\phi_k:$ neither $u$ nor $v$ is reachable from the other in less than $k$ edges.  Using the compactness theorem let’s consider any finite subset $\Delta_0\subseteq\Delta$.  It is of course satisfiable - it is sufficient to get a finite chain (path) of appropiate length.

So thanks to the compactness theorem $\Delta$ is satisfiable. As you can see here, I don't manage to reach a contradiction. I show where I got stuck in order to show you my reasoning and (no)skills.

Be forgiving for me, please :) Try to explain me it in possiblily easy way and try to sell intuition please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've concluded is that there is a model of $\Delta$ which is not connected as a graph - so, it *satisfies* König's lemma, since in particular it is not a tree!

I suspect you are misunderstanding what an infinite path is. An infinite path in a graph is a sequence of vertices $v_1, v_2, . . .$ such that $v_1Ev_2Ev_3E...$. Two vertices infinitely far apart do *not* constitute an infinite path; in particular, an infinite path has no "end".

In fact, I think you've copied the problem incorrectly. Let $\Delta$ say "There are exactly two vertices, and no edges at all." Then any model of $\Delta$ is not a tree. I think the problem you're supposed to solve is:

> Show that there is no $\Delta$ such that the models of $\Delta$ are exactly the trees with no infinite paths.

Note the iff: if $T$ *is* a tree with no infinite paths, then $T\models \Delta$.

Here's a hint for this problem. Consider the expanded language with new constant symbols $c_1, c_2, c_3, . . . $, and the theory $$\Delta'=\Delta\cup \{c_iEc_{i+1}: i\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ Do you see why $\Delta'$ has a model? And do you see what that model has to do with the original problem?

Comment: I properly copied problem. However, problem stated by you is also very interesting. Be honestly it is not easy to see why $\Delta'$ has a model. After all, You require impossible things: (1) tree, (2) no infinite paths, (3) there is infinite path.  Of course each subset of $\Delta'$ is satisfable, so using compactness thorem also $\Delta$ is satisfable. I think that I didn't get your hint

Comment: By compactness, since each finite subset of $\Delta'$ is satisfiable, $\Delta'$ is satisfiable. And as you observe, this yields a contradiction - so the original assumption, that $\Delta$ exists, must be incorrect. Does that make sense?

Comment: @HaskellFun Re: the problem, do you understand my point that the problem as stated is *false*?

Comment: Yes, you use standard trick. Lets suppose that there exists (by contrary), then extend by some constants and formulas, use compactness thorem. However, what about problem stated in my question ?   Your problem is slightly different

Comment: @HaskellFun I know. *As I stated above in my answer and my previous comment, the problem you've given is **false**.* Do you see why? (I gave a counterexample . . .)

Comment: Hmmm, is it possible to repair this problem to do it solvable ?

Comment: @HaskellFun *That was the point of the problem I gave in my answer* - I think that's what the problem actually is intending to ask.

Comment: ok, thanks you very much!!!!!